# Why ever link files instead of #include them?

Tags: c, compilation

Why should one ever compile various source code files into various object files and then link?

Wouldn't it be much easier to `#include` them in main.c and then just compile main.c?

Example:

A program that has one function foo and main:

```
void foo(void);

int main() {
        foo();
        return 0;
}

void foo(void)
{
        // do things.
}
```

The normal approach would be to sepparate this into 3 files:

foo.h

```
void foo(void);
```

main.c

```
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
        foo();
        return 0;
}
```

foo.c

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo(void) {
        // do things.
}
```

Then one would compile them and link the .o generated.

The questions are:

1.- Is there any reason to not do the following?

2.- If so, when would it be preferable to do the following, and when not?

My approach:

foo.h

```
void foo(void);
```

main.c

```
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
        foo();
        return 0;
}

#include "foo.foo"
```

EDIT: foo.foo

```
void foo(void) {
        // do things.
}
```

This way I would just care about compiling main.c

This looks to me more natural, as everithing goes "copy pasted" into main.

I already know that if the program is closed-source, you want to provide the compiled file with the headers, but I put the open-source tag because of that.

Comment: real projects have quite a bit more code than `main` and `foo`, and more than one person working on them simultaneously

Comment: Try it with a project of a medium size and see how many troubles you will get.. Not speaking of precompiled libraries and objects...

Comment: One definition rule?

Comment: How do you `#include` a binary library?

Comment: @Olaf I put the last line, because I know that sometimes it's the only option, but I was talking about when it is possible.

Comment: That has nothing to do with closed source.

Comment: Well, if I have a binary library, it is may be a standard C library, in which case I can #include it normally, or I have its source code, in which case I could #include its source code, or it is closed-source, right?

Comment: @Kerrek SB I have defined everithing only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.- Is there any reason to not do the following?

Avoid `#include`ing `.c` files.  Developers (and software tools) tend to treat `.c` files as translation units.

The object files that `.c` files create can be left alone once compiled, unless it changes or one of their dependencies (like a header file) changes resulting in a faster build.  If everything is `#included` into a file with `main`, that would have to be rebuilt with every change to every file.

EDIT: after `foo.c` was renamed to `foo.foo`

I would also avoid calling C conventional files with some unique extension, as C programmers (and development tools) don't know how to deal with them either.

> 2.- If so, when would it be preferable to do the following, and when not?

Never IMO.  Huge `static` tables might be acceptable, but I'd still put them in a `.h` file.

If the program is as simple as described in the comments below, I'd probably keep it as one translation unit, as you have in your first code sample.

Comment: For your first line: You could call foo.c foo2.h or foo.foo of whatever you wanted, that was not the point, and for the second, while a good reason, is only true for builds that spend more than a few seconds.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito You're not calling files whatever you want on my project. Declarations/prototypes go in `.h` files, function definitions/source code go in `.c` files. There are no hard and strict universal rules I'm aware of for organizing code. You organize code into different files the same way you organize code in a single file into functions; it's grouped according functionality, reuse, and ease of maintenance. I have plenty of "dixie-cup" utilities I've written that are a few functions in `main.c`. It depends on the best fit for the situation.

Comment: No, it _is_ the point -- linguistic conventions matter, for your question as it stands now.  Builds that "spend more than a few seconds" encompasses a lot of software, arguably most software.  Why bother splitting up a translation unit at all if it's so small?

Comment: I have edited the question :)

Answer (score 4):

One of the (many) reasons is compilation speed: if you put all your code into one file, like your approach does, you have to recompile the entire project every time you change something.

If your project is split into multiple files (objects), you only have to recompile the parts corresponding to the files that have changed, then redo the linking step. This is usually done using a *build system* (the classic example is `make`) which looks at all your source files, all your object files, and updates the ones that are out of date.

Compilation speed isn't a big issue for small projects, but on larger ones it certainly is, especially with C++: building from scratch can take hours or sometimes days, so you want to be able to reuse as many object files as possible.

Comment: So, for small programs (50-100 functions) the #include would be fine?

Comment: For really, really small utilities, I would just put it in one ordinary file (`myprogram.c`, no `foo.c` or anything). For anything larger than that, I would use a build system. I don't think I would use your approach - but in the end, it's up to you, of course.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: Don't you even think about it! Having definitions in header files (except for `inline` functions) is a strict **don't**. Every senior knowing his job will get a heart-attack first and give you one once back from the clinic. Learn about "information hiding", "namespace pollution", etc. Let apart compile-time aspects.

Answer (score 1):

What if a lot of different applications use the same resources?

Is it best to statically compile the same code into different applications? Objects can be shared and linked dynamically at runtime.